# Remainder Theorem Technique

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Determine the remainder when $(x^4-1)(x^2-1)$ is divided by $1 + x + x^2$ (HMMT 2000, Guts Round)

A. Write the division in the form:
$$(x^4-1)(x^2-1)= (1 + x + x^2)Q(x) + R(x)$$

B. Multiply both sides by $x-1$:
$$(x-1)(x^4-1)(x^2-1)= (x^3-1)Q(x) + R(x)(x-1)$$

C. Substitute $x^3=1,x\neq1$, and reduce the resulting equation:

$$(x-1)(x-1)(x^2-1)= R(x)(x-1)$$

D. Divide both sides by $x-1$:
$$R(x)=(x-1)(x^2-1)=x^3 -x - x^2 + 1=-(x^2+x+1)+3=3$$

> For someone who knows the method, **is it valid to skip Steps B and D**, directly substitute $x^3=1,x\neq1$ and use the fact that $x$ is a cube root of unity to get $x^2+x+1=0$.

Comment: Yeah, you don’t need steps B and D. $x^4-x$ is divisible by $x^3-1$ which is divisible by $x^2+x+1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What about x^2+x+1=0. Can you do that directly?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can skip those steps.

The verbose equivalent is that $$\begin{align}(x^4-1)(x^2-1)&=(x^4-x)(x^2-1)+(x-1)(x^2-1)\\
&=(x^2+x+1)x(x-1)(x^2-1)+(x-1)(x^2-1)
\end{align} $$

So $(x-1)(x^2-1)$ has the same remainder as $(x^4-1)(x^2-1)$ when dividing by $x^2+x+1.$

---

Answering the question in comments, yes, you can replace $x^2+x+1$ with zero.

Here, you can write:

$$(x-1)(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x-1)(x+2)$$

So you get the same remainder for $-(x-1)(x+2)$ as $(x-1)(x^2-1).$

Comment: How does $(x^4-x)(x^2-1)+(x^2+x+1)x(x-1)$

Comment: @LalitTolani Forgot the $(x^2-1)$ term. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the valuable and kind criticism, I was able to fix my answer in the end now.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate method:**

[In the spirit of my answer to your linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237919/generalization-of-remainder-theorem-technique/4238327#4238327), we recognize that $ P (x) = x^2 + x + 1$ can be "simplified" with $ Q(x) = x-1$ to give us $P(x) Q(x) = x^3 -1 $, and hence

$$ \begin{align} & ( x^4 - 1 ) (x^2 -1 ) \\
= & (x^3 -1 ) A(x) + (x-1)(x^2 - 1)  & (1)\\
= & (x^3 -1 ) B(x) + (-x^2 - x + 2 ) & (2) \\
= & (x^2 + x + 1 ) C(x) + 3. \\
\end{align}$$

Notes:

- In step (1), this uses that $ x^4 - x = (x^3 -1)D(x)$
- In step (2), this uses $(x-1)(x^2 -1) = x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 = (x^3-1) E(x)  - x^2 -x  + 2 $.

Comment: Why does it change from  $A(x)$ to $B(x)$ from Step 1 to Step 2?
Also, $(x-1)(x^2-1)$ will give you an x^3 term. How do you handle that in your method?

Comment: @Starlight Why not? Note that I didn't require these unknown polynomials to be distinct. Also, they are actually different, and in particular $ A(x) + 1 = B(x)$.

Comment: @Starlight FYI  I don't think my answer should be accepted because it doesn't (directly) answer your question of "is it valid to skip Steps B and D" as I'm not using your approach as written.  Thomas's answer to this particular question is much better than mine. I'm just showcasing what I consider to be the underlying idea to approach this question without too much machinery.

Answer (score -1):

**Alternate method:**

$(x^4 - 1)(x^2 -1)$ has a degree of six, we can write:

$$(x^4 -1)(x^2-1)=Q(x) \left[ 1+x +x^2 \right] + R(x) $$

Evaluate (1) at $\{  \omega, \omega^2 \}$:

$$ \begin{align} R( \omega) &= ( \omega-1)(\omega^2 - 1)= ( \omega -1)( \frac{1}{\omega}-1) \\
 R( \omega^2) &= (\omega^2 -1)(\omega-1) =  ( \omega -1)( \frac{1}{\omega}-1) \end{align} $$

This means that, $$xR(x) -(x-1)(1-x) = (x - \omega)(x- \omega^2)$$

Rearrange for the answer which is $R(x)=3$.

Note: $(x^4 -1)(x^2-1)$ when divided by $1+x+x^2$ must give a polynomial less than degree two. This follows via the remainder. [See Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Comment: I don’t see how you get $R(1).$ You get $$0=3Q(0)+R(0),$$ which doesn’t let you conclude $R(0)=0.$ Also, your final line is wrong - $R(x)$ is supposed to be a remainder, so it should have degree less than $2.$

Comment: I've edited the answer but remainder degree less than two is a bit confusing

Comment: How do you got expression of $R(x)$

Comment: I have fixedd it now @LalitTolani, could you please tell me if it makes complete sense?

Comment: I didn't understand how you got the equation after _This means that_

Comment: Consider the quantity $$ \begin{align} xR(x) -(x-1)(1-x)&= (x- \omega)(x-\omega^2) \\ R-(x-1)( \frac{1}{x}-1)&=(1- \frac{\omega}{x}) (1 - \frac{\omega^2}{x})  \end{align}$$

Evaluate at $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ we see the equation is true. Combine this fact that $R$ is neccesarily less than degree two, you are done.

Comment: This "quantity" seems to be out of nowhere. Can you please elaborate a bit more?