# Generalization of Remainder Theorem Technique

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

**Generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237066/remainder-theorem-technique)**

$$\frac{x^{2021}}{x^3 +x^2+x+1}$$
We wish to determine the remainder for the expression above. As in the linked question, write
$$x^{2021}=({x^3 +x^2+x+1})P(x)+ R(x)$$
To eliminate the term with P(x) let
$$x^3 +x^2+x+1=0\Rightarrow x^4 =1$$
We must then have:
$$R(x)= x^{2021}=x^{2020}\times x=1 \times x =x$$

**Second Example**

The remainder of $x^{2023}$ when dividing by $x^3+x^2+x+1$ will be after reduction:
$$x^{2023}=x^3=-(x^2+x+1)$$
(You can write this more formally using the Remainder Theorem, but this is a shorter version).

**Further generalization**
We can generalize this technique. To find the remainder when dividing by
$$1+x+x^2+...+x^n$$
substitute
$$x^{n+1}=1,x\neq1$$

Is this correct?

Comment: A cyclotomic polynomial of any degree? There are no [cyclotomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) polynomials  of odd degree except $1$.

Comment: Will change. It's not cyclotomic. It is about the pattern. Thanks.

Comment: The ultimate generalization is the Chinese Remainder Theorem (for rings and ideals, but in this case for complex polynomials), the fact is that you can factorize each $1+x+x^2+...+x^n$ as $(x-\xi)...(x-\xi^{n-1})$ where $\xi$ is an $n$th root of unity. These linear polynomials are co-prime, and for each individual polynomial you can use the remainder theorem (where the trick is to use the fact that $(\xi^k)^n = 1$ for all $k$). The trick can easily be formulated from here.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Just to clarify, you meant to write $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}$

For example, $1+x+x^2$ has roots which need to be cubed to get 1.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter I changed the question to explicitly show how the remainder theorem is used here.

Comment: When I wrote the answer I did not see your edit where you removed the tag abstract algebra.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter In retrospect, having the tag Abstract Algebra invited answers at a higher level of abstraction then I intended. I really would like to stay at the level of (real coefficient) polynomials, and Remainder theorem.
Using some nice results from Abstract Algebra is good, but this is more competition-math oriented than proof-oriented.

Comment: @starlight What is the question here? Is your intention of the question is why the method works or just does the method always work? For the latter answer is : yes, it works.

Comment: @user1972 Yes, the primary purpose is to confirm that the method always works. Some explanation with complex numbers "under the hood" is good as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to blindly using "eliminate the term", a simple explanation of why that works is just algebraic manipulation:

$$\begin{align} & x^{2021} \\
= & (x^4 -1 ) A(x) + x \\
= & (x^3+x^2+x+1) B(x) + x.\\
\ \\
& x^{2023} \\
= & (x^4 -1 ) C(x) + x^3 \\
= & (x^3+x^2+x+1) D(x) + x^3 \\
= & (x^3+x^2+x+1)E(x) + (-x^2-x-1).\end{align}$$

Note: Of course, I'm using that $ x^{2020} - 1 = (x^4 - 1) \times F(x)$, which could be demonstrated directly via algebraic manipulation.

**General idea:** If we want to divide by the polynomial $P(x)$, which has a "simpler" form of $P(x) Q(x)$, then we can write it out step by step.
This could be applied even if $P(x)$ isn't a factor of $ x^n - 1 $.   The hard part is guessing what $Q(x)$ could be to "simplify" the polynomial.

Here's a worked example, with the solution hidden.

> What is the remainder when $x^{2021} $ is divided by $x^2 + 2x + 2$?

> Using Remainder-Factor theorem might be a slight pain (esp if someone isn't comfortable with complex numbers) as the roots are $-1 \pm i$, which we have to take to the 2021 power and equate to $Ax+B$.

> However, if you recognize the Sophie-Germain factorization $ x^4 + 4 = (x^2 - 2x + 2 ) (x^2 + 2x + 2)$, we see that
>  $$x^{2021} = (x^4 + 4 ) A(x) + 4^{403} x^5  = (x^4 + 4)B(x) - 4^{404} x.$$

Here's an example of you to practice on:

> What is the remainder when $x^{2021} $ is divided by $x^4 - 2x^2 + 2$?

Answer (score 0):

The observation which you made is nontrivial.

Actually when you take $x^4 = 1$ and conclude that $x^{2021} = x$ then we can not immediately conclude that the remainder is $x$ because what you have observed here is if $a$ is a number such that $a^4 = 1$  then $a^{2021}= a$ . Note that $a = \pm 1, \pm i$ satisfies this equation. The correct way is to do is write
$x^{2021} = g(x)q(x) + r(x)$ where $g(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ and $r(x)$ is the remainder. Since $g(i) = g(-i) = g(-1) = 0$ we have $i^{2021} = r(i), (-i)^{2021} = r(-i)$  and $(-1)^{2021} = r(-1), r(-i) = -i$ and $r(-1) = -1$.

By remainder theorem for polynomials, we may assume that $r(x)$ is at most quadratic and then it is easy to see that the only polynomial satisfying the above condition is $r(x) = x$. A similar approach can be used in the other example that you gave.

Actually your pattern works in general.

**In general:**

Assume that all polynomials have rational coefficients.

Let $p(x)$ be an irreducible factor of largest degree of  $g(x)$ and $a$ be a number such that $p(a) = 0$ . The field $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(p(x))}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and the isomorphism is given by $c_0 + c_1 x + \ldots + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + (p(x)) \mapsto c_0 + c_1a + \ldots c_{n-1} a^{n-1}$ where $n = \deg p(x)$

Consider a polynomial $f(x)$ then by division algorithm there exist $r(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that $f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x)$.  We can write $g(x) = p(x)q_1(x)$ and $f(x) = p(x) q(x)q_1(x) + r(x)$ hence the remainder of $f(x)$ when you divide by $g(x)$ is same as when you divide by $p(x)$ if $\deg r(x) < \deg p(x)$. So $f(x)  + (p(x)) = r(x) + (p(x))$. But $r(x)+(p(x))$ is equivalent to $r(a)$, so it is sufficient to write  $f(a)$ in terms of $c_0 + c_1 a + \ldots c_{n-1} a^{m-1}$ where $m < \deg p(x)$.

So in your case, you showed that if $g(x) = x^3+ x^2 + x + 1$ and we have $p(x) = x^2 + 1$. So you can choose $a = i$ so that $f(a) = a$ now using the isomorphism we see that $r(x) = x$.

**Note:** If $a$ is a rational number it may be difficult to point out the exact form of remainder for example if $g(x) = x^2-1$ and $f(x) = x^{2021}$ then you may take $a =1$ and see that $f(a) =1$. However $r(x) \ne 1$ but $r(x) = x$ and this kind of confusions arises. So this works better if $a$ is irrational.

Comment: Did you see the other questions that I linked to. There I used a more detailed approach where I multiplied and divided. But the final answer is the same. 
Here I have just taken a shortcut.

Comment: When you assume $x^n =1$ and then whatever you write in terms of $x$ is not a polynomial; so your shortcut happens to work correctly but formally we can not accept that as a valid argument.

Comment: Can you elaborate? At which point  am I writing an expression that is not a polynomial?

Comment: For example, when you write $x^4 =1$ this is an equation and not a polynomial. The numbers satisfying $x^4 =1 $ are $a = \pm1 , \pm i$. When you write $x^{2021} =x$ you are using the fact that $a^4 = 1$. This is trivial; for example $(-1)^{2021} = -1$. In reality you are not calculating the remainder; you are just evaluating the remainder at the roots  of  the equation $x^4=1$.

Comment: A feature of contest math is that it asks questions of students on topics of which they do not have a through understanding. For those who like maths, it is often a process that takes them towards a deeper understanding, and overall I think the benefits are more than the drawbacks. 
This question (and answer) are framed to be done by someone who does NOT have an understanding of complex numbers - though of course it would be better to have an understanding. Sort of like a  number of properties in Calc I are stated and used (and proved later only if the student takes Analysis).

Comment: In that context, would you tell a seventh grader to learn complex numbers before attempting this question? Or is there something that can be salvaged for him?

Comment: I am very sorry to tell you I really do not have any idea about the contest math that you are referring to; your question was about the correctness of generalization of the technique and I answered affirmatively with appropriate reasons.   Keeping complex numbers aside, taking $x^{n+1} =1$ immediately implies that $x = 1$ (or $x=-1$ whenever applicable), and in this case the whole shortcut breaks down.

Comment: If someone is unaware of complex numbers then they can use this shortcut for problem-solving without knowing why it always works.  I am not sure if someone can reason why this shortcut always works without using complex numbers.  The complex numbers are hiding in the step where you substitute $x^{n+1} =1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129161/discussion-between-starlight-and-infinity-hunter).

Comment: -1 for the following reasons: 1) That $r(x)$ is at most quadratic follows from the definition of remainder for polynomials, not from the polynomial remainder theorem. 2) You are factoring OP's polynomial $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = (x+1)(x^2+1)$, whereas OP is multiplying the polynomial $(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x+1) = x^4 - 1$.  3) You seem to be forgetting that we need to find the polynomial such that $ r(a_i) = f(a_i)$ for all the roots, but instead say that the end that "for $a = 1$, if $ f(a) = 1$, there is confusion about whether $r(x) = 1$ or $r(x) = x$".